# How to convert the html to text in python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to convert html to text in python. I'm looking for clean text which should have proper spacing and new lines.

I have tried BeautifulSoup but I see the overlapping text like below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """Html code"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')   
print(soup.get_text())
```

I'm getting the below output

> Retrieving image **informationConverting** image **formatsScaling**, cropping, and rotating **imagesAdding image**, text, and....

But this should have been properly spaced(bold ones).

Is there any other modules to this?

Html [Source](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/44686.htm).

Comment: Can you show us exactly what output you're getting, formatted correctly? What is `soup`?

Comment: I have updated the code now

Comment: its really clear what you are asking, please re-evaluate your questions towards this so we can all help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet worked.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class _HTMLToText(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self._buf = []
        self.hide_output = False
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag in ('p', 'br') and not self.hide_output:
            self._buf.append('\n')
        elif tag in ('script', 'style'):
            self.hide_output = True
    def handle_startendtag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'br':
            self._buf.append('\n')
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == 'p':
            self._buf.append('\n')
        elif tag in ('script', 'style'):
            self.hide_output = False
    def handle_data(self, text):
        if text and not self.hide_output:
            self._buf.append(re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text))
    def handle_entityref(self, name):
        if name in name2codepoint and not self.hide_output:
            c = chr(name2codepoint[name])
            self._buf.append(c)
    def handle_charref(self, name):
        if not self.hide_output:
            n = int(name[1:], 16) if name.startswith('x') else int(name)
            self._buf.append(chr(n))
    def get_text(self):
        return re.sub(r' +', ' ', ''.join(self._buf))


def html_to_text(html):
    parser = _HTMLToText()
    try:
        parser.feed(html)
        parser.close()
        return parser.get_text().strip()
    except:
        return None
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: see this snap shot]

Try this code, you will get text only.

`soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html5lib")
text = soup.get_text(strip=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `get_text()` argument to specify how to space between elements:

```
print(soup.get_text(" "))
```

For more information check [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text).

Comment: Hi this works, but I wanted to parse the data exactly like as I'm viewing it in a browser. If I give an argument("\n") instead of " ", There is two empty lines in the output.